# Data-Binding Syntax error

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

I have a gridview in asp.net web page. The datasource comes sql server table. I want each cell's maximum length less than 50.
I got an error.

Thanks for helping me to fix it.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="OrgContactName" SortExpression="OrgContactName">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("OrgContactName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# (Eval("OrgContactName").Length>50)?Eval("OrgContactName").SubString(0,50):Eval("OrgContactName") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

The error:

> Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Length' and no extension method 'Length' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Obviously your TemplateField can't have Length property. Or at least it might be Eval("OrgContactName").Text.Length. Can you change the <asp:Label /> with <asp:TextBox MaxLength=50>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try Eval("OrgContactName").toString().Length>50 .... etc Eval will return an object, so you need to cast as String if you want to access "Length" property. Try it out.